# 'CLRObject' could not be created

Tags: rest, web-services, clr, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm consuming a rest web service in a job in AX 2012.

I use UTF-8, and when I run my job, I get the error:
"'CLRObject' could not be created" in line :

```
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

my code is :

```
  postData = strfmt('My json');
```

new InteropPermission(InteropKind::ClrInterop).assert();

url = "my URL";

request = System.Net.WebRequest::Create(url);

System.Net.ServicePointManager::set_Expect100Continue(false);

request.set_Method("POST");

utf8 = System.Text.Encoding::get_UTF8();

byteArray = utf8.GetBytes(postData);

request.set_ContentType("application/JSON");

request.set_ContentLength(byteArray.get_Length());

dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.get_Length());

dataStream.Close();
   try

{

```
   response = request.GetResponse();
```

}

catch (Exception::CLRError)

{

postdata = "";

}

dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(dataStream);

returnValue = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

please be informed that for the same URL and post data (JSON) I can get correct data in Postman(), but I face the issue in AX.

and I know some thing is wrong with my Unicode, because when I test the same as above code, with another URL and post data for another web service, it results in a response for me, that in it all "&" characters are replaced with Unicode "\u0026" !!!!!

would you please help me?

Comment: Have you tried Fiddler or Charles Proxy to capture the data to examine?

Comment: thanx @AlexKwitny for your comment , it is solved now , and I've posted answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys please be informed that issue solved by adding timeout to request.
I thought it may be useful for some one.

```
request.set_timeout(100000);
```